# AJAX call not working when async: true

Tags: asp.net, ajax, jquery, asynchronous

So I want this AJAX-call to run asynchronously but it only works with async: false

```
    var url = 'Default.aspx/CheckLogin';
    $.ajax({
        async: true, // works with async: false
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: url,
        data: '{"email":"' + email.val().trim() + '", "password":"' + password.val().trim() + '"}',
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            alert("success!");
        },
        error: function (result,something,error) {
            alert("Error: " + error);
        }
    });
```

EDIT:

When async is true the alert will show immediately with "Error:", that is no error msg.
The CheckLogin function is pretty slow so when it actually runs it it takes a while.

Any idea of what I'm doing wrong?

EDIT 2:

This is some info I got from chrome://net-internals/#events:

```
    t=1381258516496 [st= 0] +REQUEST_ALIVE  [dt=12]
    t=1381258516497 [st= 1]   +URL_REQUEST_START_JOB  [dt=11]
                       --> load_flags = 142737665 (ENABLE_LOAD_TIMING | MAYBE_USER_GESTURE | REPORT_RAW_HEADERS | VALIDATE_CACHE | VERIFY_EV_CERT)
                       --> method = "POST"
                       --> priority = 2
                       --> upload_id = "0"
                       --> url = "http://localhost:1176/web_new/Default.aspx/CheckLogin"
    t=1381258516497 [st= 1]      HTTP_CACHE_GET_BACKEND  [dt=0]
    t=1381258516497 [st= 1]     +HTTP_STREAM_REQUEST  [dt=11]
    t=1381258516508 [st=12]        CANCELLED
    t=1381258516508 [st=12]     -HTTP_STREAM_REQUEST
    t=1381258516508 [st=12]   -URL_REQUEST_START_JOB
                       --> net_error = -3 (ERR_ABORTED)
    t=1381258516508 [st=12] -REQUEST_ALIVE
```

Comment: what happens when you try with `assync:false` ? some errors from console will be helpful.

Comment: What doesn't work with async: false ?

Comment: What makes you think it's not async? Just remove that property?

Comment: How do you trigger the request?

Comment: You should open up your web inspector and take a look at the network activity tab. Within there, you will be able to see exactly what happened to the request.

Comment: @MatthewBlancarte it has the status cancelled if that's what you mean

Comment: @OriginalUtter How long does it take to show that it has been cancelled? Does it happen right away? Are you using `$.ajaxSetup` to set the global timeout property, by chance? Are you using any jquery plugins?

Comment: @MatthewBlancarte Yeah it happens right away. I'm not using $.ajaxSetup but a few jQuery plugins :)

Comment: @OriginalUtter is your edit backwards? your code comment doesn't match your edit comment, they're opposites.

Comment: @KevinB what do you mean? I have not edited the code if that's what you're asking

Comment: *"When async is false the alert will show immediately with "Error:", that is no error msg."* however in your code you say `async: false` works. *confused* which is it? does `async: false` work or does it not work. In either case, with the given code, `async: false` vs `async: true` should have absolutely no difference in which alert happens.

Comment: Oh sorry, `async: false` still works I meant `async: true` in the edit

Answer (score 0):

Async true is the default for ajax.  There are times when you need to set it to false, for example, you might make another ajax call inside your callback , in that case, you will need to set outer ajax call to async false and the one in the callback to true.
Also, since your making a call to a code behind, make sure to format your data correctly and the codebehind webmethod is static.  Other than that, your ajax looks ok.